# Dates of Munda Lagoon Festival in 2023

Tags: festivals, solomon-islands

I would like to know when the Munda Lagoon Festival will be this year (2023) in the Solomon Islands.

Is there a website with more information about this year's festival?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I see many references to the Roviana Lagoon Festival, which appears to be held in Munda. Could that be the same thing? That was in July.